# Prove that $f(x,y)=e^{-(x^2+y^2)^{-1}}$ is $C^\infty$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Prove that $f:\mathbf{R}^2\to \mathbf{R}$ given by $f(x,y)=e^{-(x^2+y^2)^{-1}}$ is $C^\infty$, and give the Taylor polynomial of order $n$ in $\vec{0}$.

I need to show that all partial derivatives in $\vec{0}$ need to be zero, i.e. $D_1^{k_1}D_2^{k_2}f(0,0)=0$. From there, I don't know how to proceed. Any help would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know that $e^{-\frac 1 {x^{2}}}$ is $C^{\infty}$ on $\mathbb R$ with all derivatives 0 at the point 0?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes in the one variable case this can be easily shown. How does that help?

Comment: The same proof applies for partial derivatives of $f(x,y)$. The coefficients in the Taylor expansion are the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$.